# Convert Android Project to Maven

Tags: android, maven, github

I am hoping to using Roboelectric and roboguice with a project I am taking over. To do this I need to convert the current project to maven. I have been looking at this

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted

I am wondering if I need to do anything different to convert the project as I am not starting from scratch.

Also is there anything in particular I need to do when pushing the project to github?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it with a project that was already created with eclipse.

First I added the ANDROID_HOME to my /etc/launch.conf

```
setenv ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r12
```

To get the local jars of the SDKs and put in local Maven repository, I used the [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer)

Just clone the repository and run mvn install (optional for just one version add -P 4.2 )

Then I used the pom.xml from roboelectric as a sample and just edited the things I needed. [Roboelectric Quick Start](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/maven-quick-start.html)

Be sure that the folder structure is the same as maven folder structure with /src/main/java and /src/main/test

Have not used RoboGuice for my project, but should be just to include

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
    <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the content of my pom.xml file, I'm using target 16 as with 17 I get an error for Roboelectric 1.1.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- To get this locally use https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.2_r1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Make sure this is below the android dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>   
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ -->             <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>16</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```